# change image position depending on where the mouse is how can i get it to work in ie?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was wondering if someone could shed some light as to why it isnt working on ie 8 or 9. Its workign fine on chrome and firefox.

Here is my code:

```
var image_src = {


            middle: "background-position: 730px 0px;",
        left: "background-position: 730px 480px;",
        topleft: "background-position: 730px 960px",
        top: "background-position:730px 1440px;",
        topright: "background-position:730px 1920px;",
        right: "background-position: 730px 2400px",
            bottomright: "background-position: 730px 2880px;", 
        bottom: "background-position:730px 3360px;",
        bottomleft: "background-position: 730px 3840px;"



    };

    var Hsection = $(document).width() / 3;
    var Vsection = $(document).height() / 3;

    console.log(Hsection);
    console.log(Vsection);

    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
            var mloc = {
                x: event.pageX,
                y: event.pageY
            };

            // TOP ROW
            if( 
                (mloc.x < Hsection) &&
                (mloc.y < Vsection)
            ){
                $(".tryme").attr("style", image_src.topleft);
            }else if( 
                (mloc.x > Hsection && mloc.x < Hsection * 2) &&
                (mloc.y < Vsection)
            ){
                $(".tryme").attr("style", image_src.top);
            }else if( 
                (mloc.x > Hsection * 2 && mloc.x < Hsection * 3) &&
                (mloc.y < Vsection)
            ){
                $(".tryme").attr("style", image_src.topright);
            }

            // MIDDLE ROW
            else if( 
                (mloc.x < Hsection) &&
                (mloc.y > Vsection && mloc.y < Vsection * 2)
            ){
                $(".tryme").attr("style", image_src.left);
            }else if( 
                (mloc.x > Hsection && mloc.x < Hsection * 2) &&
                (mloc.y > Vsection && mloc.y < Vsection * 2)
            ){
                $(".tryme").attr("style", image_src.middle);
            }else if( 
                (mloc.x > Hsection * 2 && mloc.x < Hsection * 3) &&
                (mloc.y > Vsection && mloc.y < Vsection * 2)
            ){
                $(".tryme").attr("style", image_src.right);
            }

            // BOTTOM ROW
            else if( 
                (mloc.x < Hsection) &&
                (mloc.y > Vsection * 2 && mloc.y < Vsection * 3)
            ){
                $(".tryme").attr("style", image_src.bottomleft);
            }else if( 
                (mloc.x > Hsection && mloc.x < Hsection * 2) &&
                (mloc.y > Vsection * 2 && mloc.y < Vsection * 3)
            ){
                $(".tryme").attr("style", image_src.bottom);
            }else if( 
                (mloc.x > Hsection * 2 && mloc.x < Hsection * 3) &&
                (mloc.y > Vsection * 2 && mloc.y < Vsection * 3)
            ){
                $(".tryme").attr("style", image_src.bottomright);
            }

    });
```

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gkgHk/5/) of this code.

Comment: please add some of your code

Comment: Could you clarify "isnt working"? What is it specifically that is wrong? When I try it in IE9 it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet explorer doesn't go well with console.log()...

```
if (typeof (console) !== "undefined"){
console.log(Hsection);
console.log(Vsection);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gkgHk/6/

Comment: Oh yes... if you do not open the developer tools it will not be defined... that ie magic.

Comment: thank you very much :D, thanks chris for the edit still new to stackoverflow.